# Change views directory per route in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to set the `views` directory for each route individually, rather than using `/views/` for all of them.

So I have a main folder for each view, which has the route and the view in it:

```
var main = require('./main/main.js');
var test = require('./test/test.js');
app.use('/', main);
app.use('/test', test);
```

How do I tell that route to look in `/main` and `/test` for the view files, rather than in /views for all of them?

I want to be able to just pass the file name in `res.render()`, rather than a relative path.

Adding multiple views with `app.set('views', ['main','test']);` is okay, but I'd rather have the views linked to just that route, in case there are files with the same name in different folders. There's also the problem that it expects the layout file to be in the same folder, when I want them all to use the same layout file.

Answer (score 2):

Use Express [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to change view directory based on the router, You can write a middle either in application level or router level based on your application needs.

Below is the example for application level middleware to change view directory based on route,

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.path === '/main') app.set('views', './views2');
    else app.set('views', './views');
    next()
})
```

Code snippet will check for the `request path`, If it is `/main` route it will use `views2` directory otherwise it will use `views` directory.

Comment: This technically works, but I believe app.set('views') sets the view directory for the whole app, meaning if it doesn't get set every time, you'll be left with the wrong directory. Also not sure if it could mess up if multiple people requested pages at the same time.

Comment: This code will change view directory for every request. You can also write common `app.set()` and remove the else part. So it will change directory only for particular route.